# PHP - Adding a Trailing Slash (.php/) Results in the Page displaying with Errors

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've currently come across a problem with my site. If someone types in http://mysite.com/index.php, it works fine and displays index.php as it should. However, if someone types in http://mysite.com/index.php/, index.php loses most of its images and now acts as being a folder, even though it is not. This happens on all my .php files.

However, on other sites, this issue does not happen. I've been thinking of using this htaccess code:

```
# Remove garbage info after .php
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.php)[/.] http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question is basically...what is the best solution to this issue?
In addition, if I use thae htaccess RewriteRule I mentioned above, would pages like /test.php?id=5 be stripped down to just /test.php (basically removing everything after .php)?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The best way of dealing with this is creating a single entry point for your site.

So, in your .htaccess you could write:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now you will enter always in index.php and from there you can do with the url what you like:

```
$url = rtrim( $url, '/' );
$request = explode( '/', $url );
```

Have a look at my [tutorial/blog](http://www.ganymedes.be/index/blog/2).

Comment: Well, this issue I have isn't present ONLY for index.php...it's present for all my .php files :s

Comment: JvdBerg's solution will catch all your pages/php files then pass them through index.php (which will be a new file, not your existing index.php).